What is the SAS URL of the Integration Account?

I tried searching on the relevant infrastructure (Integration Account), but I was unable to find any access token like the one available for a storage account. I reviewed the available documentation and settings, but it seems the Integration Account doesn't expose a similar token for authentication or authorization. This has left me unsure of how to proceed with securing the access for my processes. Could you provide guidance on obtaining the necessary credentials or access token for the Integration Account?


Which connector you are using to connect to integration accounts?

While creating a connection using AS2 connector, you need to provide the Callback URL of your Integration account in the place of Integration Account SAS URL.


In this way, you can establish a connection with integration account.


@VenuraSiriwardhana Did the given solution work for you?
